# Document class gsm-l's ToC is messed up

Tags: fonts, spacing

I'm writing a text using document class `gsm-l` but the number of the sections overlap with the section symbol `§`, like this:

[image]

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{gsm-l}

\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}           
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{foo}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}

\section{foo}

\section{foo}

\chapter{foo}

\section{foo}

\section{foo}

\end{document}
```

I think the problem is either with `\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}` or `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. I tried commenting each one of these packages with `%` separately, and when I commented the two above (again, one at a time!), the problem was fixed. I don't know why this is happening. What do I do?

Comment: Where can we find this `gsm-l.cls`?

Comment: [Here](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/monopackages), in "Graduate Studies in Mathematics", then in "AMS-LaTeX" option.

Comment: I tried another fontenc: `\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}`

Comment: @IvoTerek Note that `gsm-l` has nothing to do with the issue, except for the fact that it make the table of contents use the § glyph.

Comment: Then using `gfsartemisia-euler` along with any class that used the `§` glyph would give the same problem. I think I get it, then

Comment: @IvoTerek Yes, I added an example to my answer with the `article` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bug in the Artemisia-Euler font in the T1 encoding: the `§` character is assigned zero width. When the OT1 encoding is used, the glyph has the correct width.

A fix for using the T1 encoding which is necessary when typesetting in Portuguese, otherwise hyphenation will be hindered up to being almost impossible, is as follows, instructing LaTeX to fetch the glyph from the OT1 encoded font:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{gsm-l}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}           
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}       
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts}

\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}
\usepackage{dsfont}

% fix the width of the § glyph
\UndeclareTextCommand{\textsection}{T1}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textsection}{OT1}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}

\S1

\section{foo}

\section{foo}

\chapter{foo}

\section{foo}

\section{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Note

The `gsm-l` class has nothing to do with the issue, except for the fact it shows it, since it uses the § glyph in the table of contents.

Here's a really minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}

\begin{document}

{\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont\S1}

{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\S1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

From the output it's clear that `§` has zero width in the T1 encoded font. The proposed workaround has no consequences on hyphenation, because § doesn't participate to it anyway.

I checked all Artemisia-Euler fonts in the T1 encoding and all have § with zero width. This is bad and good news together: it's bad because it's a bug; it's good because the proposed hack will work independently of the current font.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently there's a fontencoding clash between `T1` and `OT1` occuring. The wrong spacings etc. vanish if `OT1` is used instead of `T1`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{gsm-l}

\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}       
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}           
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{foo}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}

\section{foo}

\section{foo}

\chapter{foo}

\section{foo}

\section{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @IvoTerek: Happy TeXing then!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Using OT1 when the language is Portuguese means that hyphenation will not succeed whenever a word has an accent, which is normal for the language.

Comment: @egreg thanks for the tip! Yes, this would be a problem later.. +1 on your answer too.

Comment: @IvoTerek: Transfer the `accept` to egreg then!

Comment: @egreg: Sorry, but I lack this knowledge about hyphenation of particular encodings